# WP_query private posts for not logged in users (changed in WordPress 5.7)

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this code to query all private post:

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'private', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));
```

Before WordPress 5.7 this code shows all private posts even for not logged in users. Then I just hided links on this ports by the_content filter. Is was helping functions for writing a big pull of posts with cross-links. But now this code no working:

```
function no_working_links_list( $content ) {
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'private', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

    if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
        $linker = get_permalink();
        $content = no_working_links( $content, $linker );
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    endif;
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'no_working_links_list' ); 

function no_working_links( $content, $linker ) { 
    $pattern = '~(<a href="' .$linker. '">)([^<]*)(</a>)~';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $content);

   

    return $content;
}
```

Maybe someone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found, that in example above bug was not in wp_query. From WP 5.7 get_permalink($ID) for Private post will show:

https://example.com/pretty/link/ if user logged in

and

https://example.com/?p=100 if user not logged in